# Restricting HTTP Method in security.yaml doesn't work (Symfony, LexikJwk)

Tags: symfony, http, api-platform.com, lexikjwtauthbundle

I'm trying to allow only to register (POST method) a new user (route: /api/users), I tried to follow the documentation (https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/firewall_restriction.html#restricting-by-http-methods), but when I test with Postman, I still manage to see all users with the GET method.
The security.yaml file :

```
security:
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/authenticator_manager.html
enable_authenticator_manager: true
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#c-hashing-passwords
password_hashers:
    Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface: 'auto'
    App\Entity\User:
        algorithm: auto

# https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
providers:
    # used to reload user from session & other features (e.g. switch_user)
    app_user_provider:
        entity:
            class: App\Entity\User
            property: email
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    registration:
        pattern: ^/api/users
        stateless: true
        methods: [POST]
    login:
        pattern: ^/api/login
        stateless: true
        json_login:
            check_path: /api/login_check
            success_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
            failure_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure
    api:
        pattern:   ^/api
        stateless: true
        jwt: ~
    main:
        lazy: true
        provider: app_user_provider

        # activate different ways to authenticate
        # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#firewalls-authentication

        # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/impersonating_user.html
        # switch_user: true

# Easy way to control access for large sections of your site
# Note: Only the *first* access control that matches will be used
# access_control:
#     - { path: ^/api/login, roles: PUBLIC_ACCESS }
#     - { path: ^/api,       roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
```

Short version:

```
firewalls:
    registration:
        pattern: ^/api/users
        stateless: true
        methods: [POST]
```

What I should see when trying to access /api/users with the GET method is a code 401, "JWT Token not found".
But I don't, I see the users and their datas.

Answer (score 1):

I had to configure it in the access control at the end:

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/api/users, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY, methods: [GET, PUT, DELETE] }
```